# How I can create a singleton with Kotlin with params?

Tags: android, kotlin, singleton

I'm using an MVVM architecture for my application. I want to create a singleton for my repository. How I can do it? I have a look a lot of examples and I can't understand what is the best solution ...

```
class MyRepository(context: Context) : IRepository{
private var mCtx: Context
init {
        mCtx = context
    }
}
```

Comment: mCtx and the `init{ .. }` lock can be shortened by saying `class MyRepository(val mCtx: Context)`. The `val` keyword in the constructor makes the difference.

Comment: Probably, you'd like to create an instance, not a singleton. The `Context` may probably change in the future, so you may need to reset a singleton (not possible). Even more, such singleton will leak the `Context` object forever on the static reference (producing garbage)
The best approach is to use a Dependency Injection, and it can be simplified to one method that creates all dependencies for you. For more complex scenarios, a DI library may be used too

Comment: Thank you for advice... I will try to use Koin ..

Answer (score 0):

You can use dependency injection for provide singleton. [Dagger2](https://github.com/google/dagger) and [Koin](https://insert-koin.io/docs/1.0/getting-started/android/) (for Kotlin) are good libraries for dependency injection for Android.